# Get substring from HTML tags in android

Tags: android

I want a string from HTML content. I am showing some part of HTML string here:

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #999999; margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;">
<a href="http://www.youtube.com">
<img alt="" src="http://someImage.jpg">
</a>
</div>
```

I am getting this as a string from SAX parsing. Now I want only the image path : "http://someImage.jpg" as a string.

Please anybody help me. How to get that string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use regular expression . Here i post some code . Please check it.

```
String subjectString = "<a href=\"http://www.youtube.com\"><img alt=\"\" src=\"http://someImage.jpg\"></a>";
```

**Code for Getting Href Link from Image Tag**

```
Pattern titleFinder = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]*?href\\s*=\\s*((\'|\")(.*?)(\'|\"))[^>]*?(?!/)>", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher regexMatcher = titleFinder.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    Log.i("==== Link0",regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

**Code for Getting Image Path from Image Tag**

```
Pattern titleFinder = Pattern.compile("<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>" , Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher regexMatcher = titleFinder.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) 
{
    Log.i("==== Image Src",regexMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar Please assign your string value in subjectString then check the result.

Comment: Hi Chirag, thanks for your help. I am getting URL. But my HTML string is too big. Can I show you here?

Comment: @KrishnaSuthar i Update my answer now you can get image src . Please check my code for getting image path from image tag.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Chirag. I got that image URL. I am marking this answer as accepted answer. Enjoy......:)

Comment: Perfect answer @ChiragRaval

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) parser.

```
Document doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.yahoo.com").get();
Elements elements=doc.select("img");

for(Element e:elements)
 {
  System.out.println(e.attr("src"));
 }
```

Or just use Jsoup.parse(html_text) to get an instance of Document.

```
 Document doc=Jsoup.parse(html_string);
 ...
```